# Prove that $3^{2n} +7$ is divisible by 8

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

> Prove by induction that $3^{2n} +7$ is divisible by 8 for $n \in \Bbb N$
>
> So I think I have completed this proof but it doesn't seem very thorough to me - is my proof valid?

If $n=1$ then $3^{2n} +7 = 16 = 2(8)$ so true when $n=1$

Assume true for $n=k$ so $$ 8\vert 3^{2k} +7$$

If $n=k+1$
$$3^{2(k+1)} +7$$
$$3^{2k+2} +7$$
If $3^{2n} +7$ is divisble by 8 then $3^{2n} +7=8A$ where $A \in \Bbb Z$, and thus $3^{2k+2} +7=8B$ where $B \in \Bbb Z$
$$3^2 \times 3^{2k}+7$$
$$3^2 \times (8A)=72A$$
$$72A =8(9A)=9B$$

So by induction $3^{2n} +7$ is divisibe by 8 $\forall n \in \Bbb N$

Comment: Not following.  Yes, you may assume (inductively) that $3^{2n}+7=8A$ and yes, you want to argue that this implies that $3^{3k+2}+7=8B$, but where do you argue that?  It is simply not true that $3^2\times 3^{2k}+7=3^2\times (8A)$.

Comment: Do you know modular arithmetic / congruences?

Comment: You made an error. Note that $3^2\cdot 3^{2k}+7 \color{red}{\neq 3^2\cdot \left(3^{2k}+7\right)}$.

Comment: Not relevant to the proof by induction, but it is worth noting that there is a very simple proof of this fact using basic binomial expansion: $3^{2n}+7=9^n+7=(1+8)^n+7$ and after expansion all your terms are divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not correct. It sholud be done something like this: 
$$3^{2k}= 8A-7$$ so\begin{eqnarray} 3^{2k+2}+7 &=& 9\cdot 3^{2k}+7\\ &=& 9\cdot (8A-7)+7 \\ &=& 72A-56\\ &=& 8(9A-7)\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 3):

Posting this community wiki answer as a protest - instructors should not ask for proofs by induction when there are much more straightforward ones like
$$
3^{2n} + 7 = 9^n + 7 \equiv 1^n + 7  \equiv 0 \pmod{8} .
$$

Save induction for questions where it's really important.

Answer (score 1):

An option:

Step $n+1$:

$3^{2n+2}+7 =9 \cdot 3^{2n} +7=$

$(8+1)\cdot 3^{2n} +7=$

$(3^{2n}+7) +8;$

The first term is divisible by $8$ by hypothesis, so is the second term.

Answer (score 1):

We can prove it like this :
$$ 9^n + 7 = 9^n + \sqrt[n]{7}^n $$
And by using factorization :
$$ 9^n + \sqrt[n]{7}^n = (9+7)(9^{n-1} -9^{n-2}\cdot7 + ... + 7^{n-1})$$
$$ 9^n + \sqrt[n]{7}^n = (16)(9^{n-1} -9^{n-2}\cdot7 + ... + 7^{n-1})$$
$$ \frac{9^n + 7}{16} = 9^{n-1} -9^{n-2}\cdot7 + ... + 7^{n-1}$$

We have $16$ divides $9^{n}+7$ and $8$ divides $16$, so $8$ divides $9^{n}+7$ which is the same as' $8$ divides $3^{2n}+7$'

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea. Here's how to view the inductive step *intuitively* as *multiplication*

$$\begin{align}
 3^{\large 2k} &= \color{#c00}{-7} + 8a\qquad {\rm i.e.}\ \ \ P(k)\\
\times\ \ \ \ \  3^{\large 2} &= \ \ \ \color{#c00} 1 + 8\phantom{I_{I_{I_I}}}\\
\hline
\Rightarrow\ \ 3^{\large 2(k+1)} &= {-7} + 8(\cdots)\ \ \ {\rm i.e.}\ \ P(k\!+\!1)
\end{align}\qquad $$

**Renark** $\ $ Note $\, -7\! +\! 8a = 1\! +\! 8(a\!-\!1)\ $ so viewed this way, instead of $\, \color{#c00}{-7 \times 1}\,$ we get $\,1\times 1,\,$ so the above boils down to  $\, (1+8j)(1+8k) = 1+8n,\,$ i.e. $\bmod 8\!:\ 1^2\equiv 1,\ $ so the result boils down to   $\,9\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 9^n\equiv 1^n\equiv 1\,$ by the [Congruence Power Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)