# Mathematic induction: divisibility proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, divisibility

I am asked to prove that $3^{2n}+7$ is divisible by 8, for all positive integers, I have prove that:
For $n=1$, $3^{2(1)} +7=16$, then
for $n=k$, $3^{2k}+7=8P$, where P is a positive integer
and for $n=k+1$, $3^{2k+3}+7=8P$.
I have no further development and dont know how to continue...¿What should i do from here to prove?

Comment: Is it $3^{2n}$ or $3^2n$?

Comment: Sorry, i just edited the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $3^{2n} +7$ is divisible by 8](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067826/prove-that-32n-7-is-divisible-by-8) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%248%5Cmid%203%5E%7B2n%7D%2B7%24&p=1).

Comment: @Yocheved_Vered Welcome to Math SE. Note the search also turned up the similar [Use induction to "establish" the divisibility statement $8 | 5^{2n}+7$](/q/2295541), which is closed as a duplicate of [Mathematical Induction divisibility $8\mid 3^{2n}-1$](/q/1014307), with this also basically being a duplicate of your question since $3^{2n}-1=(3^{2n}+7)-8$, so $8\mid 3^{2n}-1 \iff 8\mid 3^{2n}+7$.

Answer (score 0):

You've shown the claim holds for $n = 1$. Now suppose the claim holds for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and show that this implies that it also holds for $n + 1$. So, for $n + 1$ we have

$$3^{2(n + 1)} + 7 = 3^{2n}3^2 + 7 = 9 \cdot 3^{2n} + 7.$$

Now find a way to rewrite $\left ( 9 \cdot 3^{2n} \right ) + 7$ that allows you to use the induction hypothesis to show that this number is divisible by 8.